# Google contacts API not all the field

Tags: api, contacts

I am using the following to query the Google contacts api:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/full/

But the results don't include all the details like phone number and address. 
There is no address or phone number in the result.

(You can try that google auth playground) 
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Good point! 
Sorry, my bad.. 

I am looking to obtain all the data that we store in the google contacts. 
Starting with phone.

Comment: Ok! Please edit your question instead, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a request to the **groups** feed. I think you meant m8/feeds/***contacts***/{userEmail}/full/ instead.